# Customer Navigation Links reordering not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php-7

I am trying to re-order customer account navigation links.

[image]

And I have tried out the below 2 approaches:

1. Using `move`

File Path: `\design\frontend\DasLeben\porto\Magento_Customer\layout\customer_account.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-downloadable-products-link" remove="true" />
     <move element="customer-account-navigation-my-designs" destination="customer_account_navigation" after="customer-account-navigation-orders-link" />
     <move element="customer-account-navigation-mycard" destination="customer_account_navigation" after="customer-account-navigation-my-designs" />
     <move element="customer-account-navigation-my-saved-cards" destination="customer_account_navigation" after="customer-account-navigation-mycard" />
     <move element="customer-account-navigation-address-link" destination="customer_account_navigation" after="customer-account-navigation-my-designs" />
</body>
</page>
```

I have even tried adding the `move` attributes in the corresponding link definition classes in `customer_account.xml`, but it doesn't work.

2. Using `sortOrder`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
      <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-my-designs-link">
        <arguments>
          <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">my-designs</argument>
          <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">My Current Designs</argument>
          <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">210</argument>
        </arguments>
      </block>
    </referenceBlock>
  </body>
</page>
```

Both the approaches have no effect on the link account in customer account. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Update customer_account.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-custom">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">contact</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">My Current Designs</argument>
                </arguments>
        </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**please put your path correct**